# Bootstrap menu button outside of screen width on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Working on http://thecraftedgarden.net. It has a bootstrap fixed navbar set up. 
For some reason the mobile button is off the screen, the navbar is too wide on mobile devices. In order to duplicate the issue you must use a phone android or iPhone or you can use device mode within chrome. It does not occur in chrome if you just size the window down. Its as if the code for the mobile menu is outside all the divs and body if you take a look with developer tools.

I am almost certain the issue is caused by the bootstrap.css style sheet.

Here are some troubleshooting steps I have taken.

1. I replaced the entire block of code with the code from getbootstrap.com's fixed navbar example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/, and the issue still occured.
2. I have a second style sheet additions.css, and I removed all the styles applied to the navbar and logo and the issue still occurs.

If someone could help me identify what I messed up within the stylesheet or help me decide which lines to replace that would be very helpful.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Ok I edited the post hope that helps, its just that the page code does not seem to be the issue, since I replaced it with the standard bootstrap fixed navbar example, and  I do not know where the issue is in the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ina a tag `<a href="http://thecraftedgarden.tlchatt.com" class="pull-left"><img src="http://thecraftedgarden.tlchatt.com/img/The-Crafted-Garden-Logo.png" class="logo img-responsive"></a>`

try to remove

```
.pull-left {
    float: left !important;
}
```

and set:

```
.logo {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the issue, however they are now displaying as separate block elements. Is there a good way to get them to float right and left of each other without the break in mobile layout?

Comment: you can use this image as a background-image :) problem solved please click green accept icon :) just make anchor tag with background image